# Find out the sum of the null values for an attributes depending upon class values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, classification

The dataset looks like

```
 class       subject   computer_buy(class)
 Junior      Science   Yes
 Sophomore   Science   Yes
 Senior      Economics No
 Junior       ?        No
 Senior      Arts      No
```

Suppose the name of the dataset is `toy_data`. I want to know the how many `?` values are there for the class value `No`

I wrote a query like that

```
   toy_data['subject'].isnull().sum()[toy_data['computer_buy']=='No']
```

The error for the above query

> IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

What should be the right approach towards the query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toy_data['subject'].isnull().sum()` returns a scalar value like `3`, `1` so you can't indexing it with `[]`.

IIUC, you can use

```py
out = ((toy_data['computer_buy']=='No') & (toy_data['subject'] == '?')).sum()
```

```
print(out)

1
```